# Issues when weight painting with low poly cage

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights, weight-paint-mode

for weight painting I'm trying to use a low poly cage painted and then aplying the weights to the high model using Data Transfer modifier.
The weights on the cage looks perfect, but when transfering weights it looks horrible.
Looking for tips
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, you could go into the top bar > Weight > Smooth and play with the Factor and Iterations value, but I guess you'll need to do for each vertex group, why not parenting again With Automatic Weights?

Comment: Hi, I tried using smooth, but doesn't helps much. Also, I'm not parenting with Automatic Weights because affects undesired parts

Comment: affects undesired parts, what do you mean exactly? It should work fine, yes you may need to correct aftewards

Comment: I'm wanting to try different workflows, that's why I'm not using it

Comment: Have you tried the Projected Face Interpolated option when you use the Data Transfer, it should smooth the vertex groups

Comment: Looking better, but now some body parts affects other ones. Like, when I move the leg, the hand's mesh breaks

Comment: I think this question, "looking for tips", is not a great question for BSE (but if you asked on blenderartists.org, I'd be happy to share some tips on this-- first tip, edit the cage's positions with live data transfer to change weights to eye.)  And I think I can already see unspecified problems showing up in comments?  This might be something where you need people working back and forth with you, and BSE isn't good for that.

Comment: Thank you, I will post there